# How to display image inside a form

Tags: 7

I want to show image insida a form I've try it with  tag inside form but it's doesnt render anything heres my code

```
$form['y']['image_div'] = array(
            '#prefix' => '<div class="image"><img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-tGbw82Gz8hA/WPR6WiOGPaI/AAAAAAAAEjk/JDPdpK3p-8wAUe2QTQbtWSdTZR_DBc-QACLcB/s640/Checkout.png" />',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
        );
```

How do I render an image inside form.inc in drupal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$form['y']['image_div'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div class="image">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#markup' => theme('image', array(
    'path' => 'https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-tGbw82Gz8hA/WPR6WiOGPaI/AAAAAAAAEjk/JDPdpK3p-8wAUe2QTQbtWSdTZR_DBc-QACLcB/s640/Checkout.png',
  )),
);
```

And in your template file:

```
print drupal_render($form['y']['image_div']);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: which template file should I put drupal_render ? tpl or template.php ?

Comment: In your tpl file of the form.

Answer (score 0):

In your function that creates the form, add a $form element for your image that uses [theme_image()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_image/7.x) to create the '#markup':

`$form['element_id'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '',
  '#suffix' => '',
  '#markup' => theme_image(array(
    'path' => file_create_url('uri_goes_here'),
    'width' => [your_image_width],
    'height' =>[your_image_height],
    'title' => t('Image title for when the pointer hovers over the image'),
    'attributes' =>  array(
      'class' => 'some-image-class',
      'id' => 'some_image_id',
      ),
    )
  ),
);`

Your 'path' element can be created using [file_create_url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7.x).

If you would like to render your image using an image style that is defined in your site, use [theme_image_style()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/theme_image_style/7.x) to create your form element's #markup:

`$form['element_id'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '',
  '#suffix' => '',
  '#markup' => theme_image_style(array(
    'style_name' => 'some_style_name',
    'path' => file_create_url('uri_goes_here'),
    'width' => [your_image_width],
    'height' =>[your_image_height],
    'title' => t('Image title for when the pointer hovers over the image'),
    'attributes' =>  array(
      'class' => 'some-image-class',
      'id' => 'some_image_id',
      ),
    )
  ),
);`